# Orthonormal Basis of a function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, orthonormal, orthogonal-polynomials

An Orthonormal Family $\{e_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a basis if and only if

$$f=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\hat{f}(n)e_n \ \ \ \text{in} \  \mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$$

where $f\in\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\hat{f}(k):=(f,e_k)=\int_\mathbb{R}f(x)\overline{e_k(x)}dx$

I am unsure how to prove this Lemma. It is apparently a Corollary from

$$\left\vert\left\vert f-\sum^n_{k=1}\hat{f}(k)e_k\right\vert\right\vert\leq\left\vert\left\vert f-\sum^n_{k=1}c_ke_k\right\vert\right\vert$$

Any hints?

Comment: The question is very unclear. I'm assuming that the condition for being a basis is that the sum holds for all $f \in \mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$. Also, what are the $c_k$ terms?

Comment: My apologise, yes you are correct and the $c_k$ terms are in complex numbers in $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Just to be clear, but you're wanting to prove this inequality for *any* $c_k$?

Comment: I've proven this inequality already, but to be completely honest I was very skeptical that this inequality holds for any $c_k$.

However I am unable to prove the first equality at all

Comment: basically you have to show two implications from which one is pretty much the definition of a basis. For the other one, have you heard of Bessel/Parseval inequality?

Comment: The idea of the second inequality is that finite sums of the Fourier Series represent the closest point projection of the function onto the span of the first $n$ terms of the orthonormal sequence. So, taking the distance of $f$ to any other point in the span will result in a larger distance.

Comment: But, unfortunately, I have one more question: how do you define "basis" in this case?

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you - A family of functions ${f_n}$ forms a basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ if for any $f\in L^2\mathbb{R}$ and any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $k$ and complex numbers $c_1,...,c_k$ such that $||f-\sum c_if_i||<\epsilon$ - it's somewhat the standard definition it seems

Comment: @user190080 I know both inequalities but it is assumed that I am able to prove it with only the use of the inequality I have given

Comment: I believe the family should also be linearly independent (not an issue with an orthonormal family of functions), but yeah, that's a standard definition for a Schauder basis.

Comment: What's the _definition_ of "basis" here?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich - A family of Orthonormal functions ${f_n}$ forms a basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ if for any $f\in L^2\mathbb{R}$ and any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $k$ and complex numbers $c_1,...,c_k$ such that $||f-\sum c_if_i||<\epsilon$

Comment: Then (assuming you know that inequality) this is clear! Let's say "the sum" is $\sum\hat f(n)e_n$. Saying $f$ is equal to the sum says $f$ is the limit of the partial sums, saying that you have a basis. And if you have a basis, then you have linear combinations of the $e_n$ that are close to $f$ in norm; that inequality says the partial sums of the sum are even closer, hence they converge to $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since orthonormal families are automatically linearly independent, the "only if" direction is trivial.

On the other hand, suppose the orthonormal family is a basis, and fix $\varepsilon > 0$. Then by definition of a (Schauder) basis, there exists some positive integer $n$ and $c_i \in \mathbb{C}$ for $i = 1, \ldots n$ such that
$$\left\lVert f - \sum_{i=1}^n c_i e_i \right\rVert < \varepsilon.$$
By the lemma, this implies
$$\left\lVert f - \sum_{i=1}^n \hat{f}(i) e_i \right\rVert < \varepsilon.$$
Now, fix $k \ge n$. Applying the lemma once more (with some of the $c_i = 0$), we have
$$\left\lVert f - \sum_{i=1}^k \hat{f}(i) e_i \right\rVert \le \left\lVert f - \sum_{i=1}^n \hat{f}(i) e_i \right\rVert < \varepsilon.$$
Therefore, by definition of a limit,
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \hat{f}(i) e_i = f,$$
and we are done.

Comment: ah thank you that does make sense - I'm assuming that when applying the Lemma for the second time, it satisfies the inequality because it is arbitrary

Comment: It also seems as though $\{e_k\}$ need not to be orthonormal

Comment: Yes, that's right. It implies that each approximation is at least as good as the previous one. And yes, $e_k$ must be orthonormal.

Comment: It must be orthonormal in order for the lemma to work. The coefficients will not be the inner products unless $e_k$ is orthonormal.

Comment: Oh yes of course - thank you for your help, much appreciated